# my UISegmentControl placed in a tableHeaderView doesn't change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

when i click on a button of my segmentcontrol i see interaction(i.e thing happen the way they should) but the buttons clicked don't gate darker (to show that they are selected). Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two check boxes in the Segmentcotrol's Attributes setting in IB that might effect the behavior that you encountered:  State: Momentary and Behavior: Enabled.

[image]

Comment: hello! it seems to be from the forcontrolstate in the [sortControl addTarget:self action:@selector(sortChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; what should i put instead of UIControlEventValueChanged

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the method you described.  But I just edited my rely with a snapshot of how I created it in the IB.  And the following code will handle the actions (you probably already got it working)

-(IBAction)mySegmentControll:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) 
    {
        case 0:  
            NSLog(@"seg 0");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"seg 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"seg 2");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
}